# calculate in convolution product

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

I have a serious difficulty to prove the following identities. Thank you in advance to help me please.

Let $\varphi$ be a test function on $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. We denote $\tau_x \tilde{\varphi}(y)= \varphi(x-y)$. ($\tilde{\varphi}(x)= \varphi(-x))$.

My question is: let $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$. How can we prove that
$$
D_y^\alpha(\tau_x \tilde{\varphi})= (-1)^{|\alpha|} \tau_x(D_y^{\alpha} \tilde{\varphi})= (-1)^{|\alpha|} D_y^{\alpha}(\tau_x \tilde{\varphi})
$$
?

Comment: What is $\varphi$? Test function or distribution? Did you try to show these identities by definition? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: sorry$ $\phi$ is an function test, i edit my post. I try but i haven't any idea, please to help me

Comment: If $\varphi$ a test function (in other words, a $C^\infty$ function with compact support), then everything can be done by the definition of a derivative. Start by studying $\nabla_x \varphi(x-y)$ and  $\nabla_y \varphi(x-y)$